# Seek Thermal Temperature Range

Tags: hardware

Can I manually set the range the Seek Thermal camera displays?  Currently the color mapping changes dynamically; I'd like this to be static.

Comment: Also, there should be a Seek-Thermal tag.

Comment: No, there shouldn't. Yours is the only question about it.

Comment: Good point.  If there start to be a lot of questions (it's a new product) then I guess we can revisit the issue of a tag.